# Prove: For each p,q $\in \mathbb{N}$, $\mu \left(\left(0,\frac{p}{q}\right]\right)$=$\frac{p}{q} \mu((0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ : $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a measure such that for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mu(A+h)=\mu(A)$. Let $c=\mu((0,1])$

Prove: For each p,q $\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mu\left(\left(0,\frac{p}{q}\right]\right)=c\frac{p}{q}$.

I have already shown that that $\mu((0,qx])=q\mu((0,x])$ for each $x\geq 0$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}$. For this I constructed the interval as such that it could be written as a union. Then I used additivity and translation invariance to obtain the result.

I tried the same approach for the question above, however now I have to deal with rationals. I am stuck in constructing the correct interval such that I can again use additivity+translation invariance.

Some hints/tips would be most welcome!

Comment: Split the interval $(0,p]$ into $q$ pieces

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the same idea but now split the interval $(0,1]$ into the $q$ subintervals of length $\frac{1}{q}$ and combine this with what you have already shown.

Comment: I get the idea, however I am stuck in using the translation invariance. I want to end up with someting like $\mu(h+(0,1])$ such that I can use the invariance.

Comment: Why not use translation invariance of $(0,1/q]$ instead?

Comment: I do not get how this is going to leed to the desired result. Don't we want to construct an interval in such a way that the q is removed from the interval. Then with some tricks using additivity we get the q outside the measure.

Comment: What i said gives you $q \mu (0,\frac{1}{q}] = \mu (0,1]$. This should be easy to see if you write things down. From there it should be also fairly obvious how to finish